# i am very confused* with these lines

Tags: grammaticality

Which ones are correct?

1. Heavens Door and Hells Door are an amazing job done by the same author
2. Heavens Door and Hells Door are amazing jobs done by the same author
3. Heavens Door and Hells Door are a good job done by the same author
4. Heavens Door and Hells Door are good jobs done by the same author

Comment: Are the titles both parts of the same work or seperate pieces?

Comment: At the very least the names of the works should be in quotation marks.

Comment: None of them are - all appear to need a genitive apostrophe